# jQuery .click() cause page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created few instances of jPlayer on my site. Every instance must be loaded through iframe tag and only one instance should playing at the same time. 
Every iframe have ID like: `"iframe_1"`, `"iframe_2"` etc.

Inside js file I've created function like this:

```
$( ".jp-playlist").click(function() {
    //some code                  
    window.parent.$('iframe_'+playingNow).contents().find(".jp-stop").click();

});
$( ".jp-play").click(function() {
    //some code                  
    window.parent.$('iframe_'+playingNow).contents().find(".jp-stop").click();

});
```

When I click any element which is attached to class `".jp-play"` or `".jp-playlist"` whole page being scrolled to top of triggered element.

Can someone help me with finding an alternative way to stop all players except playing one, or just help with fixing scrolling issue?

Comment: you might has `#` in a `href`. Please remove that and put `javascript:void(0)`

Comment: @urfusion Unfortunately I have no `href=""` element. For example `.jp-play` button looks like that: `<button class="jp-play" role="button" tabindex="0">play</button>`

Comment: I just put up idea here ,I dont implement it programatically , try to hide scrolling property of parent window on click function using some css and on opening/closing event  of particular iframe  make scrolling visible.

Comment: @Anil Thanks, but there is a problem with scrolling to the top of triggered element, not to the top of the page :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the default action of clicking on the element.

```
$( ".jp-playlist, .jp-play").click(function(e) {
    //some code   
    e.preventDefault();               
    window.parent.$('iframe_'+playingNow).contents().find(".jp-stop").click();

});
```

If the elements you are clicking on are links (`a` elements) with the `href` attribute set as `#`, it will cause the page to scroll to the top. Change the `href` to `javascript:void(0)` or equivalently, `javascript:;`.

```html
<div style="margin-top: 500px;"></div>
<a href="javascript:;">Clicking here will not scroll to the top of the page</a><br/>
<a href="#">Click here to scroll to the top of the page</a>
```

Comment: PS: you could simply: `$( ".jp-playlist, .jp-play")`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for telling me. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Also, by inspecting a bit the [jPlayer docs](https://github.com/jplayer/jPlayer/blob/master/dist/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js#L1537) something like finding the `Player` DOM element and triggering a `some_jP_Element.trigger("end")` would be much more concise than querying the DOM for some `.jp-stop` any invoking a `.click()` ... Also they lack for Event namespacing thus `.trigger("end.jPlayer")` would be a better (yet missing, AFAICS) option.

Comment: @hev1 Thanks guys, but there is a problem with scrolling to the top of triggered element, not to the top of the page!

Answer (score 0):

Let’s use the proper

```
$( ".jp-playlist, .jp-play").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code 
});
```

for jquery `e` stands for `event`.